# Reason to use dplyr::union_all over other row binding methods on a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a reason to use dplyr::union_all on a dataframe to bind two dataframes together vs other ways to bind rows? When I test it there don't seem to be differences but don't know if there might be edge cases where this wouldn't be a good idea or if there are reasons to choose it over another method. The documentation shows an example on a dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

data <- data.frame(a=rep('a', 10^6), b= rep(1, 10^6))
dt <- as.data.table(data)


microbenchmark(df1 <- dplyr::union_all(data, data))
microbenchmark(df2 <- rbind(data, data))
microbenchmark(df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(data, data))
microbenchmark(df4 <- data.table::rbindlist(list(data, data)))
microbenchmark(df5 <- rbind(dt, dt))

all((df1 == df2) && (df2 == df3) && (df3 == as.data.frame(df4)) && (df4 == df5))
# [1] TRUE
```

They all seem roughly the same speed except for `rbind` on a data.frame which seems particularly slow. There doesn't seem to be a speed reason to choose union_all over other methods.

```
microbenchmark(df1 <- dplyr::union_all(data, data))
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
df1 <- dplyr::union_all(data, data) 8.501586 10.19703 13.77899 11.62611 18.16747 25.73479   100

microbenchmark(df2 <- rbind(data, data))
Unit: milliseconds
expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
df2 <- rbind(data, data) 48.4319 50.98856 63.70163 52.65343 61.17889 180.8519   100

microbenchmark(df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(data, data))
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
df3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(data, data) 9.121883 10.36146 13.38456 11.13614 12.04666 127.5304   100

microbenchmark(df4 <- data.table::rbindlist(list(data, data)))
Unit: milliseconds
expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
df4 <- data.table::rbindlist(list(data, data)) 11.2442 11.84408 13.50861 12.37741 13.17539 22.89314   100

microbenchmark(df5 <- rbind(dt, dt))
Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq     max neval
df5 <- rbind(dt, dt) 11.02781 12.04254 15.0049 12.69404 13.36917 135.747   100
```

Comment: `rbind(dt, dt)` is fast because under the hood it uses `data.table::rbindlist` this appears with a quick search `data.table:::rbind.data.table` will show you the internal code used